# Como usar um setBackground de seleção em renderer personalizado?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Eu estou tentando usar um cell render, para que quando mostrar dados monetários, ela faça a formatação. Porém, quando aplico o render em determinada coluna, o foco nessa coluna não possui o background do restante da linha.

Para resolver isso, pensei em fazer o mesmo que fiz na minha AbstractTable, criar um método que mude a cor da linha selecionada, assim ela acaba pegando em todo a linha. Porém, por ser Default, não consegui fazer da mesma forma. Então se alguém souber uma maneira de aplicar o render que não "bug" ou que saiba como setar a cor.

Para ilustrar o problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha abstract, eu faço assim:

```
private JTable tabela = new JTable(jtmCompra) 
{
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int linha, int coluna) 
    {
        Component componente = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, linha,                  coluna);  

        if (isRowSelected(linha))//Focu na linha.
            {         

                componente.setBackground(new Color(147, 200, 255, 255)); 

            }       
     }      
}
```

Dai como "pinta linha" fica certo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Exemplo simples:

Tela Sistema:

```
package telas;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class TelaSistema extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    public static JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();
    public JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    public JMenu jmCadastros = new JMenu("Cadastros"); 
    public JMenuItem jmiE = new JMenuItem("Uma tela qualquer");

    public TelaSistema() 
    {     
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Sistema");
        getContentPane().add(jdp);
        setJMenuBar(jmb);
        jmb.add(jmCadastros);       
        adicionaJMenuItem(jmCadastros, jmiE);        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void adicionaJMenuItem(JMenu menu, JMenuItem item) 
    {    
        menu.add(item);
        item.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == jmiE)
        {
            TelaCadastroA a = new TelaCadastroA();
            jdp.add(a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
       TelaSistema telaSistema = new TelaSistema();
    }  
}
```

Tela: Cadastro

```
package telas;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class TelaCadastroA extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener
{
      public JButton jbConsultar = new JButton("Consultar");
      public JPanel jpBotoes = new JPanel();

    public TelaCadastroA() 
    {
        super("");    
        adicionaBotao(jbConsultar);
        setSize(500, 500);  
        getContentPane().add("South", jpBotoes);
        jpBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        Dimension tamanhoTela = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((tamanhoTela.width - getWidth()) / 2, ((tamanhoTela.height - getHeight())) / 2);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void adicionaBotao(JButton botao) {
        jpBotoes.add(botao);
        botao.addActionListener(this);
    }

      @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if (ae.getSource() == jbConsultar) 
        {
            consultar();
        }
    }

    public void consultar() 
    {       
        TelaConsultar.getTela("Consulta",  new String[]
        {
            "Código", "A", "B", "C"
        }, new DefaultTableCellRenderer[] {null, null,  new CellRenderMonetario(), null}, this);
    } 

    class CellRenderMonetario extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
    {
        private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(",##0.00");

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tabela, Object valor, boolean isSelected, boolean temFocu, int linha, int coluna)
        {
            if (valor == null)
            {
                valor = 0;
            }

            if (valor instanceof String)
            {
                setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble((String) valor)) + " ");
            } 

            else 
            {
                setText(df.format(valor) + " ");
            }
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Tela Coonsulta:

```
package telas;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TelaConsultar extends JInternalFrame implements InternalFrameListener, MouseListener {

    private static TelaConsultar telaConsultar = null;
    private String sql;
    private String[] titulos;
    private TelaCadastroA tela;
    private JTable tabela;
    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    private String proc;

    public TelaConsultar(String tituloJanela, String[] titulos, DefaultTableCellRenderer[] renderizadores, TelaCadastroA tela) 
    {
        super(tituloJanela, true, true, false, false);
        this.sql = sql;
        this.titulos = titulos;
        this.tela = tela;
        tabela = new JTable() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int linha, int coluna)
            {
                return false;//Esta tabela não pode ser editada pois é uma consulta         
            }
        };
        tabela.setModel(dtm); //Define o modelo da tabela
        tabela.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++) 
        {
            dtm.addColumn(titulos[i]);
        }
        jsp = new JScrollPane(tabela);
        getContentPane().add(jsp);
        preencher();
        //pack();
        setSize(650, 400);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        centralizaTelaConsulta();
        setVisible(true);
        tabela.addMouseListener(this);
        addInternalFrameListener(this);

        TableColumnModel tableModel = tabela.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++)
        {
            tableModel.getColumn(i).setMinWidth(70);                    
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getColumnCount(); i++) 
        {
            if (renderizadores[i] != null) 
            {
                tableModel.getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(renderizadores[i]);
                /* if (isRowSelected(i))//Focu na linha.
                {

                }*/
            }

        }
    }

    public static void getTela(String tituloJanela, String[] titulos, DefaultTableCellRenderer[] renderizadores, TelaCadastroA tela) 
    {
        if (telaConsultar == null) 
        {
            telaConsultar = new TelaConsultar(tituloJanela, titulos, renderizadores, tela);
            TelaSistema.jdp.add(telaConsultar);
        }
        TelaSistema.jdp.setSelectedFrame(telaConsultar);
        TelaSistema.jdp.moveToFront(telaConsultar);
    }

    private void preencher() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{"" + i, "Brasil - " + i});
        }

    }

    public void centralizaTelaConsulta() 
    {
        Dimension tamanhoTela = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((tamanhoTela.width - getWidth()) / 2, ((tamanhoTela.height - getHeight())) / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
        TelaSistema.jdp.remove(telaConsultar);
        telaConsultar = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Quem renderiza são os CellRenderes, defaulttablemodel em nada influi nisso. Se possivel, adicione seu renderer e um  **[mcve]** para que o código seja testável.

Comment: Mesmo o exemplo mais básico, eu acho que vou ter que postar um link pra baixar um .rar, tem problema? Vou tentar por o "menos possível" de coisas.

Comment: Complica um pouco. Faça um exemplo com alguns dados de exemplo(sem conexão com banco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está modificando a forma como esta coluna renderiza, as definições padrões da tabela não são aplicadas, por isso o método [`getTableCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) possui um parâmetro `isSelected`, para que você mesmo defina. No caso do seu código, a solução que encontrei foi checar se o campo estava selecionado, e copiar as definições de seleção padrões da tabela:

```
class CellRenderMonetario extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(",##0.00");

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable tabela, Object valor, boolean isSelected, boolean temFocu, int linha, int coluna) {
        if (valor == null) {
            valor = 0;
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(tabela.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(tabela.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            setBackground(tabela.getBackground());
            setForeground(tabela.getForeground());
        }

        if (valor instanceof String) {
            setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble((String) valor)) + " ");
        } else {
            setText(df.format(valor) + " ");
        }
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Com isso, o campo seguirá o mesmo padrão de cores de seleção do restante da tabela.

Tem várias coisas que poderia ser melhorado nesse código, principalmente a questão de organização e de responsabilidades de classes e métodos, mas isso fugiria o escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Nossa, deu certinho. Não havia pensando em mecher no render. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GustavoSantos Disponha :)

Comment: Eu tenho uma dúvida, bem próxima a do tópico, porém eu devo abrir um novo, ou posto postar nos comentários ? É que eu fiz um render para data, que não esta muito certo.

Comment: @GustavoSantos te respondi la no chat.