# Como criar TableCellRenderer para strings?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Queria saber como faço um TableCellRenderer para strings.

nesse tópico aqui: [Como usar um setBackground de seleção em renderer personalizado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163599/como-usar-um-setbackground-de-sele%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-renderer-personalizado)

eu vi que o cara tinha pra "valores". Queria saber se da pra fazer para nomes e etc?

Por exemplo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Tabela extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Tabela();
    }

    public Tabela() {

        String[][] dados = new String[][]{{"Brasil", "São Paulo"},
        {"Estados Unidos", "New York"}
        };
        String[] colunas = new String[]{"Pais", "Estado"};
        JTable tabela = new JTable(dados, colunas);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(tabela);
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        getContentPane().add("Center", jsp);
        setSize(500, 300);
        setVisible(true);        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Eu tenho uma tabela (aqui só um exemplo bem simples), e eu gostaria de poder ter um render, para que, onde eu tiver tabelas depois, eu posso formata-lãs. Queria que os nomes ali, fossem centralizados (conteúdo das linhas)

Comment: Ainda não está muito claro o que pretendes. Centralizar colunas com string nem precisa criar um renderer. É só isso que queres: centralizar a informação da coluna?

Comment: Centralizar o conteúdo das linhas. Qualquer linha q for inserida ficasse centralizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há duas maneiras que se destacam:

## - Centralizando colunas específicas

É possível definir a renderização centralizada apenas para certas colunas, definindo um renderer padrão para esta coluna de forma isolada:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//onde está zero pode ser alterado para a coluna desejada
tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
```

Repita a última linha para todas as colunas da tabela,pode ser usando um loop ou manualmente, se tiver poucas colunas.

Aplicando o código acima no seu exemplo, apenas a coluna `País` será centralizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## - Aplicando a toda a tabela

Este método alteraria todas as colunas, mas dificulta se futuramente você quiser alterar a renderização apenas a determinadas colunas.

Para isso, será necessário alterar o método `getColumnClass` do [**`TableModel`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) da tabela. No exemplo, eu fiz utilizando o [**`DefaultTableModel`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), passando como parâmetros o array de linhas e de colunas:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dados,colunas){
    
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
    }
};
```

Depois aplicar a sua tabela desta forma:

```
JTable tabela = new JTable(model);
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
tabela.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, centerRenderer);
```

Aplicado no seu exemplo, o resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema desse método é que todas as colunas serão tratadas como *String*, tornando uma melhor opção [criar um TableModel próprio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121513/28595), para que o código e sua tabela sejam de mais fácil manutenção e legibilidade. Fica a sua escolha qual método utilizar.

Comment: Esse primeiro método, não  vai apenas centralizar as colunas? Eu queria centralizar o conteúdo das linhas. Tipo, na coluna Pais, deixar Brasil centralizado.

Comment: @Javinha sim, como eu expliquei na resposta, o método um vai centralizar apenas a colunas que você definir na linha destacada. Dá mais controle do que centralizar. O método 2 centraliza tudo, pois no DefaultTableModel eu defini que todas as colunas serão Strings.